# UIButton to expand and contract UITableViewCell with StackViews, drop down views with static data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I have a tableCell, that has a UIButton and it needs to do a couple functions.

1. I need to rotate an image 90 degrees ( an up / down arrow ) that alternates between button presses.
2. Same button needs to add n amount of UIVIEWS in a UIStackView inside the same tableCell, and either show, or hide those views with static data.

for sake of thread n = 7

In my ViewController I declared a Boolean, set it to false

```
var isExpanded = false
```

Inside of cellForRowAt , I have:

```
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_:)), for .touchUpInside)
```

In the same TableViewController class file I have :

```
    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
         let cell = MyCell()
         cell.arrowImg.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotatingAngle: .pi)
        
        for i in 0..<n.count {
     cell.stackView.addArrangedSubViews(i)
}
```

I know I am missing some very basic stuff, but YouTube and stack overflow and google aren't showing me what I am missing.

Do I need the boolean at all , if I am essentially using the UIButton to toggle between two states of the tableCell ? Showing extra UIViuews / flipping the up / down arrow, or not?

And, once the UIViews are "loaded" in the particular cell that the button was pressed, how do I retain that expanded cell size after its decked when the user scrolls the cell off the screen? reloadData in the function?

Comment: I have height set as AutomaticDimension if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you want to change the layout of a cell, you need to tell the table view controller so it can update the **table** layout.

If you're using a button to change a cell's appearance - show / hide views, add views / rotate an image / etc - you need to keep track of that in your controller. Then, when the user scrolls that cell out of view and back into view, your `cellForRowAt` function can "configure" the cell to its proper state.

Comment: Thanks Don,  Configuring and adding / removing the UIViews, do these specific functions have to live in the ViewController, or can they live in the TableCell and I just call them from the ViewController, and does that Have to be called from cellForRowAt ?

Comment: @mikalooch - as a general rule, classes should only know **what they need to know**. So, for example, your cell class should layout and show/hide or rotate its subviews, and if it has a button it should handle the button tap and *tell the controller* that the button was tapped. At that point, the controller should update its data (set an "expanded" var to true or false, for example), and then either update the table with `performBatchUpdates` or reload that row. (continued...)

Comment: To properly display the row when scrolling, your cell should have something like a `configure(_ expanded: Bool)` function, and in your controller's `cellForRowAt` function, you dequeue the cell and call `cell.configure(myIsExpandedVar)`

Comment: Thank you again Don!  Im starting to get this...one last thing...right now I have a button add target function in Cell For Row At,  to unhide a view, but its unhiding views in all the cells....how do I call that addTarget on only the selected cell, without using a tag?

Comment: @mikalooch - do you have multiple rows with this cell design / functionality? And you want each to expand/collapse (individually) when its button is tapped?

Comment: Update: I can just make a protocol or a "empty" closure and call that in the cellForRowAt..oh lord my brain is fried today.

Comment: Yes  each cell can have a different number of added UIViews , this number / amount comes from a JSON payload...so its like a dropdown, or hamburger'ish, or even a tableView INSIDE a cell which will not scroll, but a tableView inside a cell is a no no...correct? that's like scrolling inside of scrolling.

Comment: Okay !! I am able to hide/unhide the particular stackView, but the full size of the view isn't yet showing. Thats constraints or just updating the tableCell I believe.